# How to set a shortcut instead of typing a part of the command 'youtube-dl -F'

Tags: youtube-dl

I haven't used youtube-dl in a while and I do remember that I set 2 shortcuts:

one for "**youtube-dl -F**"

another one for "**youtube-dl -f**"

the shortcut is something simple like ***xx*** for ***'youtube-dl -F'*** so that in the command line, I would just type **xx [URL]**

Now the thing is I dont know how I set it actually at that time and moreover I cant seem to remember what those shortcuts are (maybe they got deleted or so.. I am not sure)

Hoping someone can help me out on how to set them OR point me to a webpage where I can get those set of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

someone in a different forum helped me figure it out.

I used 'aliases' in my zsh shell on iterm2.

Apparently I set '**sd**' for "**youtube-dl -F**" & '**sdd**' for "**youtube-dl -f**"

[image: zsh image]